# Writing a simple function function in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am a fresher in Selenium. I have lots of doubt about Selenium functions. I am using Selenium RC with Java and Eclipse.

I need to write one simple function for adding two numbers. Where will I write that function inside the `test()`?

How can I call that function if we want any other object for this function? Do we need to declare any header file for calling this function? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the function is:

```
public void waitForElementExistance(final String elementLocator,
        final int seconds, final boolean exists) throws Exception {
    waitTimeFor(new Condition() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify() {
            return selenium.isElementPresent(elementLocator) == exists;
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

You write this function -- for example  -- just above the test()

You can call it in your test() like this:

```
waitForElementExistance("css=div.buttonlabel:contains(Upload)", 10, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at this helpful tutorial [part 1](http://www.bitmotif.com/selenium/selenium-remote-control-for-java-a-tutorial/), [part 2](http://www.bitmotif.com/selenium/selenium-remote-control-for-java-a-tutorial-part-2/)